# Azure Data Factory Data Flow: pipeline expression issue for timestamp string

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am working on adf from snowflake to adls using data flow:
[image]

I am using Pipeline expression:

```
@concat('SELECT * FROM mySchema.myTable WHERE loadDate >= ', '''', '2022-07-01', '''')
```

It failed with the error message:

> Operation on target Copy Data failed:
> {"StatusCode":"DF-Executor-StoreIsNotDefined","Message":"Job failed
> due to reason: The store configuration is not defined. This error is
> potentially caused by invalid parameter assignment in the
> pipeline.","Details":""}

(It worked when I directly run the query below in snowflake:

`SELECT * FROM mySchema.myTable WHERE loadDate >= '2022-07-01'`)

But when I used Pipeline expression below (removing Where clause):

```
@concat('SELECT * FROM mySchema.myTable')
```

It worked.

Or if I used Pipeline expression below (using a different Where clause without timestamp comparison:

```
@concat('SELECT * FROM mySchema.myTable WHERE loadDate is not null')
```

This also worked.

So, my question is: why the first expression failed? How should I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just using the date as a string?
i tried it with the sample sql data in Azure SQL DB and it worked !
@concat('select * from SalesLT.Customer where ModifiedDate >= 2021-09-01')

Comment: Thanks Sally, but I tried, it said SQL compilation error and it doesn't work for Snowflake. The error message: Job failed due to reason: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error:\nCan not convert parameter '(2022 - 9) - 1' of type [NUMBER(6,0)] into expected type [TIMESTAMP_TZ(9)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the **date in the string** itself as suggested by **@Sally Dabbah**.

This is my repro with Azure SQL Database for your reference:

Give the **query in the double quotes** and **date in single quotes** in the dynamic content pipeline expression like below.

```
"select * from dbo.myschema where loaddate >= '2022-07-01'"
```

[image]

Give this parameter `$query` in the **dataflow expression**.

[image]

**Pipeline succeded:**

[image]

**Data in the csv file in the sink** (to single file):

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rakesh. It's weird: I tried your approach, but I was not even to run it and the error message is: {"code":"BadRequest","message":null,"target":"pipeline//runid/6dbb28e3-2057-4cab-1fda-ae02a28e7d42","details":null,"error":null}

Comment: Oh, I tried again and checked the Expression checkbox and now it works. Thanks a lot.