# Escaping single quotes in ADF dataflow

Tags: azure-data-factory, dataflow

I am executing this query:

`select * from schema.country where country_code='abc' and country='INDIA'`

inside ADF dataflow. I am getting this query from the database so I don't want to hardcode it inside the data flow. All the data flow inputs are adding a single quotes while executing. The dataflow is failing because of parsing error.

How can I escape single quotes ?

Answer (score 4):

You can just pass your **query in double quotes** (`""`) in the dataflow to escape single quotes.

Please go through the below 3 approaches **based on your usage of query** in the dataflow.

This is my sample data from database:

[image]

1. **If you are using **Query** in the source of dataflow**, you can give the below expression in the Expression builder.

   ```
   "select * from [dbo].[country] where country_code='abc' and country_name='INDIA'"
   ```

   [image]

   **Output Data preview:**

   [image]
2. **If you want to get your query from your database**, then create a stored procedure for the query and access it inside the dataflow.

   **My stored procedure in the database:**

   ```
   create or alter procedure dbo.proc2
   as
   begin
   select * from [dbo].[country] where country_code='abc' and country_name='INDIA'
   end;
   ```

   Use this query inside stored procedure in the dataflow like below. You will get the same output as above.
   [image]
3. **If you are using **pipeline paramter to pass query** to the dataflow**, then create a parameter in the dataflow with default value. Give your `query in double quotes` in the pipeline parameters expression. Check the **Expression** check box after this.

   [image]

   Then give the `$parameter1` in the expression builder of query and execute. Please      check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72943401/azure-data-factory-data-flow-pipeline-expression-issue-for-timestamp-string/72952486#72952486) to learn more it.

   My csv in sink after pipeline execution in this process:

   [image]